# Sensitivity analysis of a fuzzy cognitive model

Tags: simulation, covariance-matrix, matrix, matrix-decomposition, sensitivity-analysis

I have a fuzzy cognitive model of inter-organizational collaboration that is represented by a 27x27 matrix.  I want to analyze the effects of individual variables.  I've read I can do this best with a SOBOL sensitivity analysis.  However, I am open to any and all other ways of accomplishing this task.  I am a total newb here, do not assume I have prior knowledge. I need simple answers with lots of pictures :)

Cheers,

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: My question is:  How do I conduct a sensitivity analysis on a 27x27 adjacency matrix?  My goal is to understand the effect of modifying the effect of individual variables on the outcome measure.  Please let me know if I need to contribute more information that will allow me to move the ball across the goal line...